# Is my understanding of how a variable works, wrong?

Tags: c++, variables, syntax

[image]

Hello. I am very new to C++ and programming in general. I am trying to build my confidence by playing around with what small components I already understand until I am as familiar as I can be before learning more. However I am stumped and getting frustrated at myself because I cant seem to make this simple piece of code work. I hope that whoever reads this understands what I was trying attempt and can tell me where I have gone wrong. please and thank you.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    char computer[100];
    char something[100];



    double price;
    double price2;
    double total = (price + price2);
    double budget;
    if (budget < total){ double need = total - budget;}
    if (budget > total ){ double surplus = budget - total;}
    double perday = total / 365;
    double remain = budget - perday;
    int A;

    std::cout << "Please tell me, the 'name' of the new computer that you would like to buy.\n";
    std::cin >> computer;
    std::cout << " How much does this " << computer << " cost?\n";
    std::cin >> price;
    std::cout << "Cool! Now tell me something else you would like to buy.\n";
    std::cin >> something;
    std::cout << "How much does " << something << " cost?\n";
    std::cin >> price2;
    std::cout << "I need to know your technology budget:\n £";
    std::cin >> budget;


    if (budget >= total)
    {std::cout << "Wow you have enough cash to get both " << computer << " and " << something << "\n with a surplus budget of £" << surplus;}

    else (budget < total) {
    std::cout << "I am sorry you lack the necessary funds right now. \n";
    std::cout << "Would you like to hear a payment plan?\n 1 for yes / 2 for no \n";
    std::cin >> A;
    }

    if (A = 1) {
            std::cout << "If you wanted to buy both " << computer << " and " << something << " \n by this time next year, you could pay £" << perday << "each day from now\n ";
            std::cout << "If I take today's payment now, you will have £" << remain << "left of your budget";}
        else return 0;}
}
```

Comment: "_I hope that whoever reads this understands what I was trying attempt and can tell me where I have gone wrong._" First of all: why do you think, that anything is wrong? Please describe the expected output, actual output, and the input provided.

Comment: you are summing variables before setting them... you should really start with basics... https://www.learncpp.com/

Comment: Hello Algirdas, thank you.

Comment: I think a thing you are misunderstanding is that variables only exist within the scope in which they are declared. They stop existing when the program section (aka scope) where they where declared is closed.

Comment: The program printed all the outputs without taking input (only the first std::cin was read and printed as expected on the next line) Am I to declare global variables to make this work? I will be taking a look at the link XraySensei  just sent as I have only been using codeacademy up until this point.

Comment: Please format your code properly, this will help you with thinking about your problem

Answer (score 2):

first of all declaring a variable within a scope is a bad habit except you plan to use that variable only in that scope.

```
if (budget < total){ double need = total - budget;}
if (budget > total ){ double surplus = budget - total;}
```

In this case, `need` and `surplus` live only between these `{ }` and can't be used outside of them. If you want to use them later in your program, make sure you declare them out of the scope.

The other thing I noticed is that assigning operator **=** in programming language is used for adding values to a variable. In your case, `if (A = 1)` won't work because cpp won't check whether A is 1 but it'll assign A to be 1. What should you do is check `if (A == 1)` with double **==**. [Check here for operators](https://www.bs.w3ki.com/x3x/images/Operators-In-C.png)

I suggest reading a good book for cpp and getting better on that way.

If you're wondering, here's a [working](https://pastebin.com/5gpK0RJw) version of your program

Comment: Thank you very much anthino12. I have a better understanding now.

Comment: *"declaring a variable within a scope is a bad habit except [...]"* This is very misleading advice. Variables should always be declared in the innermost scope that encompasses all of their use.

Comment: Concerning your [working](https://pastebin.com/5gpK0RJw) version: The final `else return 0;` looks a bit mis-leading. On one hand, this leaves the `if` branch without a `return`. On the other hand, `main()` is the one and only function with non-`void` return type which doesn't need a `return`. (`return 0;` is assumed by default.) So, in short, you could have left out the `else return 0;` completely. (Concerning the formatting, I'm even not sure whether you was aware of this.)

Comment: @Scheff I agree with you. I didn't pay attention to that, I just fixed the lines where it had an error and ran it. Great comment tho, it's worth reading

Comment: Ok thanks to everyone helping me today. Since this morning I have rewritten, and executed successfully by simplifying the code and declaring global variables (which is one thing I learned about today) I realise I have a long way to go, but the way I learn is to play and wrestle with it, thanks for the observations advice and encouragement.